# Is OPC UA Read and Write operations atomic?

Tags: opc-ua

In other words, is it possible for a server or a client to receive partial data before the transmission is finished?

I am sure this information is written somewhere in the extensive documentation of the OPC Foundation, but I think this is essential.

I am using the "atomic" phrase as used for database writes. When a programmer updates a table, the update is always atomic in the sense that it is either done or not done. We rely on the DB software for guaranteeing against the operation being only partially successful.

In the case of a PLC acting as an OPC UA server; when the client writes say 1 KByte data, are we sure that the program running on the PLC, on any instant read a part of this data while it is still being communicated and written? Since we are dealing with a very fast reading entity (the PLC) on the other side of the communication, is it possible that the PLC gets the first 100 bytes before the rest is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is provided by Flippo & Kevin in the above comments**. So this will be a recap for everyone to quickly spot:

1. OPC UA guarantees atomicity only for simple types (Integer, Double Integer etc)
2. Longer structures' atomicity depends on the specific manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

Beckhoff OPC-UA Server communicates with the Beckhoff PLC through the ADS protocol.

The default Max Size of the consistent data sent with the help of the ads router is **16 kByte** although it can be changed if needed.

This is important to understand, because the OPC-UA Server is not part of the PLC runtime environment.

When an OPC-UA client writes a node of an OPC-UA Server, the OPC-UA Server sends this data to the PLC.

In the Twincat development environment you have the option to declare a special attribute for structured types:

```
{attribute 'OPC.UA.DA.StructuredType' := '1'}
```

This tells the Beckhoff OPC-UA Server to send the data concerning that specific data structure in a consistent way to the PLC when it receives it from a client.

The Beckhoff OPC-UA documentation states:

"StructuredTypes allow you to read or write structures without interpreting each byte, because the UA Server
returns the information type of each element of the structure. Based on complex functions in modern
OPC UA SDKs, OPC UA Clients can search and interpret this structural information."

Therefor, regarding data consistency, it is also important that your OPC-UA SDK (client) is modern enough to be able to "search and interpret this structural information".

Comment: I am using Beckhoff Ads directly. Does that mean that a Ads struct write can be considered atomic?

Comment: The communication between the ADS-Server and the PLC ADS-Client is data consistent.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! Do you happen to have a source which backs this statement? I searched the Beckhoff website but was not able to find something stating this. I'd like to add a link in my source to back some assumptions I make :-)

Comment: The ADS-Technology is a core element of the Beckhoff system architecture.Take a look at the device concept: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_ads_intro/9007199370899851.html&id=

Comment: As you can see the communication beetween ADS-Devices inside the Twincat runtime is done via ADS

Comment: If this communication were not data consistent all the system would fall apart..You have communication between cores and between plc-runtime and nc-runtime which must be data consistent to work deterministically.

Comment: How this is done technically, it's a Beckhoff secret and one can only speculate. I guess the ADS-Router engine plays a big role in ensuring that the data is transfered consistently.

Answer (score 2):

> In the case of a PLC acting as an OPC UA server; when the client writes say 1 KByte data, are we sure that the program running on the PLC, on any instant read a part of this data while it is still being communicated and written?

You can be certain that any server will not be processing any read or write until the request has been fully transmitted by the client. There is no facility in OPC UA for dealing with streaming/partial requests from clients.

That said, how the server handles that 1KB of data it just received as a write is not covered by spec. There is no guarantee that it is written atomically to whatever the backing/underlying datasource may be (in memory, shared memory, a file, another device on the network, etc...).

I do believe that most OPC UA servers built in to PLCs are probably doing the right thing to ensure atomicity but there is nothing in the spec that guarantees it and no way to be sure other than contacting that vendor or consulting documentation.

Comment: Thx for the answer Kevin. In other communication methods when I was not certain I always used two stage write. i.e. I wrote the 1KB, made sure every bit was on the PLC, and only after that I wrote a single bit = 1 to signal to the PLC that there was a 1KB it needed to look into. This can also be done via OPC UA. What is your experience? With A 2019 Siemens CPU 1500 OPC UA Server should I go into that trouble?

Comment: Unlike Beckhoff, Siemens complex structures are non atomic. Only primitive data types and some special TIME and DATE data types are atomic. So if you have complex data structures go with beckhoff..

Comment: *clarification: I mean as of today Siemens OPC-UA  Server doesn't guarantee atomic read and write for complex data structures (unlike Beckhoff OPC-UA Server, see my answer)

Comment: I have sent enquiry to a contact I have at Siemens to try and get a definitive answer but I have no reason to doubt @FilippoBoido on this matter.

Comment: page 221 -> Consistency of data types at the server interface: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj4sqWSvOLjAhXqwsQBHe5BD-gQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.industry.siemens.com%2Fcs%2Fattachments%2F59192925%2Fs71500_communication_function_manual_en-US_en-US.pdf%3Fdownload%3Dtrue&usg=AOvVaw1v_Hb-HOc3IBa3ROPSod9j

Comment: @KevinHerron is there an answer from your contact at Siemens? Page 221 Flippo has sent seems to indicate that he is right. Only simple data types seem to be atomic.

Comment: @Rumi my contact confirmed the same - user-defined structures are not atomic. The documentation is accurate.